# "complement the pity that"

Tags: word-choice

For example, you did something but unsuccessfully. Then you tried another way to achieve an approximation to the same goal. Can you say that

> you hope the second way can **complement the pity that** you couldn't succeed in the first way?

It sounds unnatural to me.

Comment: I would use balance, as something good balances something bad. Complementing items are usually both good, or both bad.

Comment: Though "complement the pity" sounds a little odd, what strikes me more is "in the first way". (I'd prefer "you couldn't succeed the first time".)

Comment: It sounds unnatural partly because you have a very long chain of modifiers: you're almost at "complement of the pity of the failure of the first try." Usually, rephrasing in a simpler way fixes problems like this, as in @StoneyB's answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. The noun *pity* only has the sense “something to be regretted” in the collocation ***a*** pity (or an abbreviation of this in which *a* is omitted), and even then only as a complement of the verb *BE* or in free-standing fixed phrases:

   > It’s a pity she can’t come.
   >   His promotion is a real pity.
   >   What a pity!
   >   Pity you didn’t succeed.
   >   “But I’ll be fired!” he cried. “Pity,” she shrugged.

   In other contexts the noun *pity* means “sympathy”.
2. *Complement* is probably not the verb you want here—it means “make complete” or, more loosely, “enhance by addition”. Perhaps you are thinking of *compensate for*, meaning “counteract” or “make up for”.

   > You hope the second way will compensate for the disappointment of your previous failure.